# getting stragne unexpected error sometime using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using `ActionBarShelock` and some time get force close with this error cant find how to handle it .

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sps/com.sps.ui.activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.app._ActionBarSherlockTrojanHorse.onCreatePanelMenu(_ActionBarSherlockTrojanHorse.java:52)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:556)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:60)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:154)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:393)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restorePanelState(PhoneWindow.java:1677)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1627)
    at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:928)
    at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:900)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2037)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: sorry i am new to android what do you mean ???

Comment: This is a bug in copied code from the support library. The `dev` branch on GitHub for the project has corrected this. It will be included in the next release (probably in the next two weeks).

Comment: post it as an answer so i can check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the r7 support library, the version on which the current release (4.1.0) of ActionBarSherlock is based, the `FragmentManager` class checked if `mActive != null` before dispatching menu events to the fragments contained in the `mAdded` list. This code was copied into ActionBarSherlock since it uses its own `MenuItem` type and does its own dispatching.

In a subsequent release of the support library, it was found that this check was no longer representative of whether or not `mAdded` had been instantiated with a list or not. Commit [464b6f3c](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/commit/464b6f3c93dda03359ec2d37c8205065922f2994) changed the conditional check to `mAdded != null`.

ActionBarSherlock has not had a release since this fix was made. However, it was updated on the [`dev` branch](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/dev) in commit [69fe6fd](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/commit/69fe6fd6ec0d5373175faca95366bb4d04b88498) to be included in the next release.